# How to reset the firebase auth account password for unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I have an **problem**. I am working on an unity project and here I used **firebase database** system.
I want to add a **reset password** system but didn't find the documentation how to do with unity.
If any one know the system please let me know. I will very glad to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on [sending a password reset email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email) for Unity contains this code fragment:

```
string emailAddress = "user@example.com";
if (user != null) {
  auth.SendPasswordResetEmailAsync(emailAddress).ContinueWith(task => {
    if (task.IsCanceled) {
      Debug.LogError("SendPasswordResetEmailAsync was canceled.");
      return;
    }
    if (task.IsFaulted) {
      Debug.LogError("SendPasswordResetEmailAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
      return;
    }

    Debug.Log("Password reset email sent successfully.");
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I used it with the `ContinueWithOnMainThread` helper as with most of the other Firebase methods. Otherwise I end up with some strange behaviours.